# Wordpress SQL query to get who last edited posts

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I want to get who last edited posts. I've got this query:

```
SELECT meta_value, post_title, post_modified
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID=wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key='_edit_last'
```

In this query the result of `meta_value` is user ID, but I want to get user name (`user_login` from `wp_users` table). How can I do that?

Comment: You need a join to `wp_users` on `meta_value`.

Comment: @ shA.t Yes, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your answer is like this:

```
SELECT meta_value, post_title, post_modified, wp_users.user_login
FROM wp_posts
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID=wp_postmeta.post_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_users ON wp_users.ID=meta_value
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key='_edit_last'
```

Comment: I can't believe it's so simple. I was trying something else, but I was close.

Thank you! Work like a charm.